# Uploading on github after deleting the github repository

Tags: visual-studio, github

I have a project and i want to upload it on github that i already uploaded but deleted the repository on github and now whenever i try to upload from visual studio the upload button doesnt show please help me[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly the problem, you deleted a GitHub repository by going to its settings and clicking 'Delete this repository' in the danger zone. You now want to push (upload) your local git repository to the accidentally deleted GitHub remote repository.

If this is the case you should first recreate the GitHub repository from your account as you would do to create a new repository. Then you should follow the instructions to add your repository. This would probably include a terminal command that you should run in your project directory (folder): `git add {{ name of stream (i.e. origin) }} {{ branch (i.e. master) }} {{ link to remote repository }}`

If this is not the case or you need another explanation, please provide more information.